# Change results in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I would like to manipulate the result I get from a query.

I have a set of 2.5m rows and there are 10 different ID's for a status. These statusses are not mapped in another table but I would like to manipulate the result I get in SQLyog.

```
What I would like to do is:

Count(Id) | Status
------------------
500.000   | 1
750.000   | 2

convert into a result

Count(Id) | Status
-------------------
500.000   | Initial order
750.000   | Cancelled
```

Can this be done in the query? Note that I'm not using PHP or a browser to display the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
      count(*) as TotalRecs,
      case status
         when 1 then "Initial Order"
         when 2 then "Cancelled    "
         when 3 then "whatever     "
         else        "all others   "
      end case as WordStatus
   from
      YourTable
   group by 
      2
```

Comment: Should `end case` be `end` in the `end case as wordstatus` part? I don't remember CASE ... END having a `CASE` after the `END`.  Nor should `group by 2` work

Comment: @Cyberkiwi END CASE closes the opening CASE STATUS... As for Group by 2, that is legit as it is referring to the ordinal column position in the query (which is represented as WordStatus). So your counts are grouped by the wording context instead of the numerical representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can either inline it in a case statement

```
select COUNT(id), 
    case status
    when 1 then 'initial order'
    when 2 then 'cancelled'
    # without an else, the rest go to NULL
    end status
from tbl
group by status    # yes, just on status
```

Or I would strongly encourage you to create a reference table for this

Tbl `Status` contains 2 columns `ID` and `Description`

```
select COUNT(tbl.id), status.description
from tbl
LEFT join status on status.id = tbl.status
group by status.description
```

Comment: Thank you as well, this is also the solution :)